# PHP to replace backslash found in MySQL field's string

Tags: php, mysql, backslash

I have a table with two fields.  One of these fields (ncatalogNumber) contains a string that sometimes begins with \ followed by a 10 digit number.  I have been trying to use a MySQL update based PHP query string to replace these backslashes with ''.

If I issue the mysql query directly to the MySQL server it works fine, but as a query string in PHP it is giving the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\', '')' at line 1

Here is my PHP query string:

```
  $query3 = "UPDATE ndrive SET ncatalogNumber = replace(ncatalogNumber, '\\', '')";
```

I can't simply delete the first character of the string as sometimes it is a number and not a troublesome back slash.

Comment: Have you tried `\\\\`? Sometimes you need to double escape.

Comment: That was exactly what it needed to function.  Thanks!